# d3.data skipping the first row of data

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code that works great, except when I iterate through my data set, the first row (the 0 index) is getting skipped.

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x",function(d){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(d);
    return xScale(d.year-1980);
  })
```

Note the `console.log(data)` returns my full data set, including the first row so the data is there!

But `console.log(d)` shows all rows after and including my second row of data - it drops the first row.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you already have a `rect` element when you run that code. This element is getting matched to the first data row and thus the `.enter()` selection is missing it.

Comment: D3 is very powerful yet too vast. Its not widely used or published too. It harnesses the power of javascript entirely. Wish we had more tutorials on D3

Comment: Move console.log(data) outside of your x function(d). It gets printed for each d. Maybe, you missed it. Then, post some of your output.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff , you saved at least few hours of my time !

Comment: I found this to be a lifesaver too. It took some time to come up on the searches. ```d3 selectall .data skipping first element``` didn't cut it.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue with similar code, and fixed it based on [Lars Kothoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff)'s comment.

In my case it made sense to change the `selectAll` to work on a g element, more like so:

```
svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data);
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x",function(d) { return xScale(d.year-1980); });
```

You could also differentiate the rects with a class:

```
svg.selectAll("rect.year")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x",function(d){ return xScale(d.year-1980); })
    .classed("year");
```

Comment: The bottom approach is the simplest solution.  Nice.  Just change `selectAll("rect")` to `selectAll("rect.year")`

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it seems if there is already an element, it gets "skipped" by the .enter()

```
<html>
<head>

<title>D3 Test</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> 

var theData = ["James", "Sue", "Ben"]

var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")    
    .data(theData)
    .enter()
    .append('p')
    .text(function (d,i) {
      return " i =" + i + "data =" + d;
    });

</script>

</html>
```

Produces

i =0data =James

i =1data =Sue

i =2data =Ben

But if you add a p element in there, it'll skip it.

```
...[previous code]

<body>
<p>Here is the first p tag that "James gets matched too"</p>

</body>

...[previous code]
```